# Include doesn't work after query creation

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core

I have a simple query:

```
var fruits = from fruit in db.Fruits
             where fruit.Name = "Apple"
             select fruit;
```

This works fine. This also works:

```
var fruits = from fruit in db.Fruits.Include(props => props.RelatedFruits)
             where fruit.Name = "Apple"
             select fruit;
```

However, this does *not* work:

```
var fruits = from fruit in db.Fruits
             where fruit.Name = "Apple"
             select fruit;

if (includeRelated)
    fruits.Include(props => props.RelatedFruits);
```

`RelatedFruits` is always empty, whereas if I include the `.Include()` in the initial query, it is correctly populated.

I was under the impression that this should work fine, since it's adding the `.Include()` to the query before it's actually called.

Is this a bug in Entity Framework Core, or am I misunderstanding the way `.Include()` works?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that by doing only this:

```
if (includeRelated)
  fruits.Include(props => props.RelatedFruits);
```

you are essentially telling EF to forget about that configuration. If you assign the return value of it to your `fruits` variable it should work fine:

```
if (includeRelated)
  fruits = fruits.Include(props => props.RelatedFruits);
```

This becomes evident once you think about how the query is interpreted by the LINQ translator. The LINQ extensions which EF supports are backed by its query provider which will tweak the behavior or the statement generated etc. by your query. By not assigning the result to the original (or a new) variable, the `fruits` variable will hang on to the same expression tree it did before going into the `if` branch, essentially causing this configuration instruction to be ignored.

Comment: That did it, thanks! Unfortunately I can't accept the answer for another 8 minutes.